# Inline code in R markdown PDF file is not displayed correctly

Tags: r, r-markdown

My R markdown PDF file does not show inline code as it should. This only works correct when choosing HTML as output file.

Generally inline code should look like `this`. So when highlighting some words within my text, I want it to `look like this`.

E.g. I want to have this sentence in my PDF output:
A good way to pronounce `%>%`when reading code is `then`.

Instead I get what you see here:

[image: attached image]

The image shows how the inline code is displayed in my output. Only changed font and style, instead of grey background.

I use exactly the same code as I am using here at stack overflow: `` these signs before and after the text I want to highlight.

Any tip how to fix this? I need PDF output, and not HTML.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: FYI, *"inline code should look like `this`"* is predicated on the default styles of the canvas. Here, it's HTML. For your problem, it is LaTeX, which is a completely different beast. There are many differences in styling, some of them can be wrangled to do what you want, some are not easy in the LaTeX way of doing things. I suggest you look into whether this kind of thing is easy with LaTeX itself (neither R nor Rmd), perhaps at [tex.se], and then work to bring that tex-macro into your rmarkdown yaml front matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text like `` `this` `` is translated into the LaTeX command `\texttt{this}`. LaTeX commands can be changed, so we can modify the `\texttt` command to create a color box:

````
```{=latex}
\definecolor{codegray}{HTML}{cccccc}
\let\textttOrig\texttt
\renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{\textttOrig{\colorbox{codegray}{#1}}}
```
````

Add the above at the beginning of your Rmd document (right after the YAML header) to get a gray background for you inline code snippets.